# How to spread out the squished line chart in angularjs nvd3?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am trying to set up intervals for every 3 months for each year in x axis of the following line chart, but all I get are the squished data points for each year.

[image]

Here is my code for the chart :

```
$scope.options = {     
        chart : {
                type : 'lineChart',
                margin: {
                    top : 50,
                    right : 100,
                    bottom : 50,
                    left: 100
                },
                x : function(d) {
                    return d.x;
                },
                y : function(d) {
                    return d.y;
                },
                useInteractiveGuideline : true,

                xAxis : {
                    axisLabel : 'Date',
                    ticks : 10,
                    tickSize : 1,
                    tickFormat : function(d) {
                        return d3.time.format("%m/%Y")(new Date(d));
                    }
                },
                yAxis : {
                    axisLabel : label,
                    tickFormat : function(d) {
                        return d3.format(4)(d);
                    }
                }
            },
            title : {
                enable : true,
                text : label
            }
        };
};
```

Here is my code for data :

```
$scope.data = getData(label,dates,data);

function getData(label,dates,data) {
        var graphData = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
            var newDate = parseDate.parse( dates[i] )
            var para = parseInt(data[i]);
            graphData.push({
                x : newDate,
                y : para
            });
        }
        return [ {
            values : graphData, //values - represents the array of {x,y} data points
            key : label, //key  - the name of the series.
            color : '#ff7f0e', //color - optional: choose your own line color.
        } ];
};
```

The chart should look like this. This is the Excel representation.
[image]

Comment: Well, what does your data look like?  Do you have a bunch of points all at the same time?  How did you expect the line chart to look like?

Comment: Agree. Posting a JSFiddle/Plunkr would help.

Comment: Sorry. I have added the expected line chart. The data is that there is a count for each day of the month of every year.